# Meet of two subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

First, what is the definition of the meet of two subgroups? Second, is this a common notion? I ask because I'm reading through Mac Lane and Birkhoff and they ask for us to find the join and meet of some subgroups, yet they never define it in the book (they do define join) -- at least, I cannot find where it is defined.

Comment: It's the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

As the_fox mentioned it is the intersection. That term comes from order theory, the meet is the infimum of a poset. That definitions agrees with the intersection of groups when you consider the subgroup lattice. More info can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet).